# line break in DataTable and GridView

Tags: asp.net, string, gridview, datatable

I am actually trying to put a line break in a string in an asp.net project using c#.I put this String in a DataRow that I add to a datable named "ds".Once it's done I link this datable ds to the gridview.
This is my code:

```
            risque.projet = dt.Rows[i]["fk_projet"].ToString();
            risque.release = dt.Rows[i]["fk_release"].ToString();

            //Create the String for adding to the row
            String test = "Project:"+risque.projet+"<br>"+ "Release: "+risque.release;
            drow["Description"] = test;
            Label1.Text = test;


            //Add the row to the datatable.
            ds.Rows.Add(drow);

            //Link the datatable to the gridview
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

I want this output:

Project:.......

Release:.......

but I always have : Project:.... Release......

I tried many solutions:
-System.Environment.NewLine
-\r\n
-\n

EDIT:Code of my gridView.I have nothing in my gridview because all is created at runtime.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" PageSize="5">
        <SelectedRowStyle Wrap="True" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

But nothing works. The br tag works but only when I display my String in a label.

Do you have an idea of my error?Do you have a solution? I spent too much time on this.

Thank you,

Quentin

Comment: Can you show the aspx code for the Gridview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work put the tag in, but set the column's HtmlEncode property to false.  By default all fields are HtmlEncoded, which of course, stops html tags from working like html tags.

However, if you're doing this, you'll want to htmlencode the field values manually in code-behind to prevent XSS.

```
"Project:" + Server.HtmlEncode(risque.projet )+ "<br />" + "Release: " + Server.HtmlEncode(risque.release)
```

(I prefer the [Anit-Cross-Site Scripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814) Library's implemmentation of HtmlEncode to Server.HtmlEncode, but that's another subject.)

Comment: Hi David,your solution is good but your line doesn't work as well.I still search the solution.Apparently I have to initialize the cell of my gridview with server.htmlEncode.

Comment: Ah.. I see.  You're letting the runtime auto-generate columns.  I think you're going to need to set AutoGenerateColumns = false and specify the columns.    You can't specify the HtmlEncode from code-behind.  The only other alternative I had was to use a TemplateField, which, again, would mean specifying the columns.

Comment: Thank you David,I just find the solution.I am going to post it.

Comment: Good deal!  I look forward to seeing it!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of concatenating break tags you could use a carriage-return character, vbCrLf in this case.

Carriage-return characters are used for print and display functions.

However, vbCrLf does not exist in C#. The value of vbCrLf is "\r\n". So try this below.

```
string vbCrLf = "\r\n";
String test = "Project:" + risque.projet + vbCrLf + "Release: " + risque.release;
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the grid column into template column and the label will do the magic. The 
 will work if binding data to a label.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need: `<br />`  instead of `<br>`